# Helvetica as font in Tikz

Tags: fonts, illustrator

I would like to use Helvetica (regular or italics) in a tikz figure.

By specifying the `{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` and using the `pxfonts` package, I am able to obtain kind of the same font:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node(text) at (1,1) {Test test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, it is not recognized by Adobe Illustrator as Helvetica but as 'NimbusSanL'.

How do I specify Helvetica as a font in Tikz?

Comment: `NimbusSan` is nothing but `Helvetica`, if you are using `PDFLaTeX`, `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`, then the font name is changed as `NimbusSans`, if you follow `LaTeX -> dvips -> Ps2PDF`, then the font name was displayed as `Helvetica`...

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 1**: Thank you very much to @Marian G.

Into enviroment `tikzpicture` you can write into the `\node` the syntax

> \node[`font=\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont`] at (1,1) {Test test}

(*see the comment of the user @Marian G.*) to write in [URW Nimbus Sans](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwnimbussans/) based on Helvetica font. You can see this article into specific page of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Sans). A screenshot is put below together a MWE, and you can compile it in `pdfLaTeX`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[font=\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont] at (1,1) {Test test}; % semicolon
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**: Thank you very much also to the user @Zarko (see your comment).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{font=\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}%%%%%%%<----by @Zarko's comment
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node(text) at (1,1) {Test test}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If OP wish to use Helvetica font in all TikZ pictures, than might be sensible ad to document preamble `\tikzset{font=\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}` :-). Nice answer!

Comment: I am trying to use Amatica SC font by defining `\newfontfamily\amatica[Scale=1.0]{Amatica SC}`. The font selection works well with main text `{\amatica This is Amatica SC}`, but inside tikzpicture it is reverting to default CM font with `\node [font=\fontfamily{amatica}\selectfont] at (1.5,0) {Amatica};` Though it is working with  `\node at (1.5,0) {\amatica Amatica};` How do I define it globally?

Comment: @Damitr Excuse me for my delay for this answer. But for my humble opinion you should to ask a specific other question because thus it works the site :-(. My best regards.

Comment: Yes, I did ask https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539690/custom-font-with-tikz