# Custom font with TikZ

Tags: fonts, tikz-styles

I am trying to use [Amatic SC](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amatic+SC) with TikZ. Though I have partially succeeded in getting the results, it is not scaling with the use of `tikzset`.  I have defined a new fontfamily for this purpose and it works well with the main text. But even after explicitly defining it using `tikzset` and also at the node level with `\fontselect` I am not able to get the desired result. 
For now I am only able to use it within the node using `{\font }`. I have used the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531254/helvetica-as-font-in-tikz), but it is not working for me. What is wrong in my approach?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\amatica[Scale=1.0]{Amatica SC}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\tikzset{font=\fontfamily{amatica}\selectfont} 
% even uncommenting this does not produce the required result

\begin{document}


{\amatica This is Amatica SC}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node [fill=white,draw=blue,rectangle] at (1.5,0) {\amatica snow};% this works
\node [font=\fontfamily{amatica}\selectfont,draw=blue,rectangle] at (1.5,-1) { snow};%this doesn't
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could add `[every node/.append style={font=\amatica}]` to your `tikzpicture options` and remove font options from your `\node`s. Or set `\tikzset{every node/.append style={font=\amatica}}` in the preamble. At least that works with Arial on my system

Comment: Yes, this works! But I would like to know why the things that I tried didn't work

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess this is because you use system fonts with `fontspec` while the previous quesiton uses `T1` fonts

Comment: Ohkay, thank for the explanation.

Comment: Note that the command to use your `\newfontfamily\amatica` is `\amatica`, and if you’re going to be using NFSS commands such as `\fontfamily`, you’d normally set a `NFSSFamily=amatica` option to the `\newfontfamily` command. Does not appear to be your issue here, though.